# How to export .ASCII file in NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to know how I can transform a .csv file into raster (ASCII) within NetLogo 6.2?

Well, I can export in .csv to do the conversion later in .ASCII in another program such as R. However, I think it should be possible to export the output in .ASCII by NetLogo itself. At the same time, I would like to know if in terms of processing it would be better to export the output in .csv by NetLogo or in .ASCII? obs.: my world on NetLogo is relatively big

Thanks in advance

```
extensions [ gis ]

globals [ file output-filename ]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set output-filename "output-data.csv"
  set-default-shape turtles "person"
  create-turtles 10 [
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  ]
  initialize-data-file

end

to initialize-data-file 
  file-close-all    
  if file-exists? output-filename [
    file-delete output-filename
  ]     
  file-open output-filename
  file-print ( word "xcor, ycor" ) 
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    wander-about 
    if ticks mod 50 = 0  [    
      write-output-data who xcor ycor
    ]
  ]
  tick
end

to write-output-data [ #turtle-id #xpos #ypos ]
  file-open output-filename
  file-print ( word #xpos ", " #ypos )
  file-flush
  
  ; set file gis:patch-dataset xcor ycor
  ;  gis:store-dataset file "test.asc"
  
end

to wander-about 
  rt random 40
  lt random 40
  if not can-move? 1 [ rt 180 ]
  fd 1
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track using the GIS extension to export directly to ASCII. Whether you actually need to do this depends entirely on your application- as you say, it may be possible to do what you need simply by exporting a list of turtle coordinates, or of patch values, etc., depending on your needs. Whether you should use ASCII or csv is going to depend on your application, **but**: for all of my larger models where I actually need to export the whole world for analysis (and, more importantly, to go the other way and import my spatial data *into* NetLogo), I always use the GIS extension because it seems to be much faster. If I were only exporting turtle characteristics I would probably export to csv.

To answer your specific question here about how to export directly to ASC- here is one way. You need to set up some spatial information for the GIS extension to work with your data, but once you've done that you can create a raster dataset from patch values and export that to a .ASC file that will consist of the .ASC header in addition to a value for each patch in your world. With this example:

```
extensions [ gis ]

patches-own [ turtle-here ]

to setup
  ca
  resize-world 0 14 0 14
  ; Pull in some coordinate system 
  gis:load-coordinate-system "utm_11.prj"
  ; Set some envelope. Unless you are actually spatially
  ; referencing your model, this is just a placeholder. 
  ; If you are using actual spatial coordinates, set these
  ; appropriately or use gis:envelope-of
  gis:set-world-envelope [ 55000 50000 55000 50000 ]
  crt 10
  reset-ticks
end


to go
  ask turtles [
    rt random 80 - 40
    ifelse not can-move? 1
    [ rt 180 ]
    [ fd 1 ]
  ]

  if ticks = 50 [
    export-ascii
    stop
  ]
  tick
end

to export-ascii
  ask patches with [ any? turtles-here ] [
    set turtle-here 1
  ]
  let ras_out gis:patch-dataset turtle-here
  gis:store-dataset ras_out "any_turtle_here.asc"
end
```

This exports an ascii file that stores the `patches-own` variable called `turtle-here` that simply indicates if a turtle is present on the patch at the time of export:

```
NCOLS 15
NROWS 15
XLLCORNER 50000
YLLCORNER 50000
CELLSIZE 333.333333
NODATA_VALUE NaN
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much Luke C. It helped a lot, now I understand how gis:patch-dataset works :) Thanks thanks thanks